# Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac

Tags: macos, process

How do I find (and kill) processes that listen to/use my TCP ports? I'm on macOS.

Sometimes, after a crash or some bug, my Rails app is locking port 3000. I can't find it using `ps -ef`...

When running

```
rails server
```

I get

```
Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

The same issue happens when stopping Node.js process. Even after the process is stopped and the app stops running, port `3000` is locked. When starting the app again, getting

```
Address already in use (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Comment: A very neat solution to kill a process on ANY user-specified port can be found in @Kevin Suttle's answer below. Reproduced here for posterity: `function killport() { lsof -i TCP:$1 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 }`

Comment: @user456584 's comment above should be the accepted answer ^^^ That function worked to kill the _many_ processes i had running on a port

Comment: works after finding processes with netstat and killing the process with kill -9 command!

Comment: @richardec `kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)` not working?

Answer (score 4658, accepted):

1. You can try `netstat`

   ```
   netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000
   ```
2. For **macOS El Capitan** and newer (or if your netstat doesn't support `-p`), use `lsof`

   ```
   lsof -i tcp:3000
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer gave birth to my "death_to 'port'" script. 
(#!/usr/bin/ruby
`lsof -t -i tcp:#{ARGV.first} | xargs kill`)

Comment: The "terse" flag to lsof produces output suitable for piping to a subsequent kill: `lsof -t -i tcp:1234 | xargs kill`

Comment: If you want to know what the process is before you kill it, `ps xp <PID>`. It's always nice to find out the root cause of port conflicts.

Comment: If you only want to look for/kill *listening* processes, use `lsof -n -i4TCP:8001 -sTCP:LISTEN -t | xargs kill`. I found that if I did it without the `LISTEN` it would often kill my browser as well as a locked development server process, as the browser was also using the development port.

Comment: I have put this into my `~/.bash_profile`: `findandkill() {
 port=$(lsof -n -i4TCP:$1 | grep LISTEN | awk '{ print $2 }')
 kill -9 $port
}
alias killport=findandkill` So now I just have to type `killport 8080` and it saves me some seconds

Comment: Another tip is to add `-P` to the `lsof` command so that the raw port is visible in the output: `lsof -P -i:3000`

Comment: on mac `lsof`  is on `/usr/sbin` directory which is not in `PATH` by default.

Comment: @oma if you run the netstat command without the grep, you'll get the column names.

Comment: netstat -tulpn | grep 3000
Then kill the process id 
kill -9 id

Comment: Just curious but could `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000` sometimes return spurious results since `3000` could be present in a pid or ip? (sorry, not hugely knowledgable and hence not sure)

Comment: This post is only half the answer

Comment: I would have appreciated this answer to have find (and kill) part since I landed on this answer while searching for "find AND kill process running on a port"!

Comment: My bashprofile function is based on the above suggestions but simplified: `killport() { lsof -t -i tcp:$1 | xargs kill -9 }` Usage: `killport 5000`

Comment: If you are using macOS Monterey, the Airplay server now uses Port 5000 so you either need to change the port for your process or kill Airplay receiver in System Preferences > Sharing

Comment: On macOS Monterey you have to disable the new AirPlay functionality. Control Center stops listening to those ports when you turn off "AirPlay Receiver" in  System Preferences > Sharing

Comment: mac: sudo npx kill-port 3000 (or with
PC: npx kill-port 3000)

Answer (score 3314):

Find:

```
sudo lsof -i :3000
```

Kill:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** `-9` kills the process immediately, and gives it no chance of cleaning up after itself. This may cause problems. Consider using `-15` (TERM) or `-3` (QUIT) for a softer termination which allows the process to clean up after itself.

Comment: Sometimes **lsof -i :port** will show nothing. try **sudo lsof -i :port**.

Comment: Recommend trying `kill -15 <PID>` before resorting to `-9` for safety.

Comment: @Jamon Holmgren why? what do both do? and why is a ```kill <PID>``` not sufficient / dangerous / incomplete?

Comment: @MichaelTrouw almost a year later, but here's your answer. :-) http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8918 TL;DR `kill -15` gives the process a chance to clean up after itself.

Comment: I think this answer should say what `-9` does.

Comment: Please don't just use `kill -9` without thinking twice, and trying other signals first. It will cause a process to exit immediately, without cleaning up after itself, possibly leaving a mess behind or leaving databases in inconsistent state... Try a TERM (default for `kill`, no flag needed) or QUIT (`kill -3 pid`) first at least, and check what process you are dealing with before sending a KILL.

Comment: That cleanup is important for Java processes, I just experienced. Restarting my machine fixed the problem after killing with -9. Will be trying -15 next.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw kill command's [Man page](https://ss64.com/osx/kill.html) says that "-15" means "Termination signal - allow an orderly shutdown", whereas "-9" means "Kill signal".

Comment: When I use `kill -9 <PID>`, show error 
`kill: kill <PID> failed: operation not permitted`. 
solution is add sudo in the front.  
`sudo kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: Kill:sudo kill <PID> No need of -9

Comment: how come it is not marked as the right answer, it's the fastest way to do it

Comment: Please edit the answer and add an explanation for what `-9` does. I see some comments suggest `-15`, and an explanation will definitely be benefit others. Thanks!

Comment: difference between `-9` and `-15` is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)#Unix_and_Unix-like. `-15` is the safest and also the default option

Comment: I've never forgotten this command due to [this rap video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fow7iUaKrq4)

Comment: i like to use -9 when I'm mad at my computer program that won't quit when I ask nicely

Comment: no sudo needed on mac

Answer (score 1160):

***Quick and easiest solution***:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)
```

**For multiple ports:**

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000,3001)
```

#3000 is the port to be freed

**Kill multiple ports with single line command:**

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000,3001)
```

#Here multiple ports 3000 and 3001 are the ports to be freed

> lsof -ti:3000

If the port is occupied, the above command will return something like this: 82500 (Process ID)

> lsof -ti:3001

82499

> lsof -ti:3001,3000

82499
82500

> kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3001,3000)

Terminates both 82499 and 82500 processes in a single command.

For using this in `package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000,3001) && npm start"
}
```

In terminal you can use:

```
npm run start
```

Comment: This should be the best solution. Does both find AND kill in one short, simple command :)

Comment: I get "kill: not enough arguments" when the port is free. Is it possible to condition it to work both when is taken and when is free?

Comment: Try: `$(lsof -ti:3000) && kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)`

Comment: Based on the answer here, i have created tap
```brew tap devasghar/portkill && brew install devasghar/portkill/homebrew-portkill``` then you can do
```portkill 3000``` & for multiple ports
```portkill 3000,3001```

Comment: I tried this oneliner but I got the following:

`kill: not enough arguments`

Comment: May be because the port is already killed. Try: `$(lsof -ti:3000) && kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)`

Comment: This does not work anymore - this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127321/2750966

Comment: From the upvotes I'm still getting for this answer, I'm sure this still works for lot of people. As long as Mac uses the Linux kernel,  lsof and kill command should work without issues. I don't know what's your specific case.

Comment: If you get `kill: not enough arguments` try `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -ti:3000)`

Answer (score 317):

Nothing above worked for me. Anyone else with my experience could try the following (worked for me):

Run:

```
lsof -i :3000 (where 3000 is your current port in use)
```

then check status of the reported PID :

```
ps ax | grep <PID>
```

finally, "begone with it":

```
kill -QUIT <PID>
```

Comment: This actually seems a better answer than the one give much later by Filip Spiridonov, which has 277 upvotes against your 9. Yours was 6 months earlier, and has the same information with a bit more explanation. There is no justice...

Comment: Try `kill -TERM` (or just `kill`) before `kill -QUIT`. Not every process is going to do an orderly shutdown on SIGQUIT.

Answer (score 208):

This single command line is easy to remember:

`npx kill-port 3000`

You can also kill multiple ports at once:

`npx kill-port 3000 3001 3002`

For a more powerful tool with search:

`npx fkill-cli`

---

*PS: They use third party javascript packages. `npx` comes built in with Node.js.*

*Sources:  [tweet](https://twitter.com/brunolemos/status/1013541511231868933?s=21) | [github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fkill-cli)*

Comment: Can you share details on installing npx using brew? I tried installing it on my Mac High Sierra, 10.13.3 and it won't work.

Comment: @realPK `npx` comes with `npm` which comes with `node.js`, so it's not a separated package. Just upgrade your node.js and your npm versions.

Comment: I do Java mostly, haven't exposed myself to Node yet. I found a different way of killing service running on port. TY for responding.

Comment: The need for NodeJS and JavaScript, to kill something running on port 3000 probably rails... seems like too much overhead to me.
adding a simple line to your .bashrc or .zshrc with an alias would solve it without the need for the internet.

alias kill3000='lsof -ti:3000 | xargs kill'

then you can do: kill3000

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 198):

A one-liner to extract the PID of the process using port 3000 and kill it.

```
lsof -ti:3000 | xargs kill
```

The -t flag removes everything but the PID from the lsof output, making it easy to kill it.

Comment: You can filter out "listening" ports with: `lsof -ti:3000  -sTCP:LISTEN`

Comment: This method works best for me.  Simple one liner that clears the busy port.  Thanks!

Comment: I added a couple of functions to my profile based on this

```sh
port-kill() { lsof -ti :"$1" | xargs kill -9; }

# give process a chance to gracefully quit
port-quit() { lsof -ti :"$1" | xargs kill -QUIT; }
```

Answer (score 173):

You can use `lsof -i:3000`.

That is "List Open Files". This gives you a list of the processes and which files and ports they use.

Comment: This is a great way to find it, can you update your answer to include the easiest way to kill the command?

Answer (score 81):

To forcefully kill a process like that, use the following command

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:3000  

OR lsof -i:3000
```

Where 3000 is the port number the process is running at

this returns the process id(PID)
and run

```
kill -9 "PID"
```

Replace PID with the number you get after running the first command

[image: For Instance, if I want kill the process running on port 8080]

**Why `kill -9 PID` does not work?**
If you trying to kill a process with its PID and it still runs on another PID, it looks like you have started that process in a different account most probably root account. so Login in with `sudo su` and kill it

Comment: I tried creating an alias in ZSH:  alias port="lsof -n -i4TCP:$1" and got the following error... How to achieve this? 

$ port 8080
lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i 4TCP:

Answer (score 67):

In your `.bash_profile`, create a shortcut for `terminate` the 3000 process:

```
terminate(){
  lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 
}
```

Then, call `$terminate` if it's blocked.

Comment: You can make this flexible enough for any port: https://github.com/kevinSuttle/dotfiles/commit/9458141f40094d96952adc7c423cbdddeb909a81

Comment: And such a descriptive name =p

Comment: I have something similar to this but I pass in the port. I named my function KP for kill port.

Answer (score 63):

To kill multi ports.

```
$ npx kill-port 3000 8080 8081

Process on port 3000 killed
Process on port 8080 killed
Process on port 8081 killed
```

Hope this help!

Comment: How about using `npx` to find running ports?

Comment: Npx seems support detect port like 'npx detect-port 8080'. But seems not supporting find all running ports.

Comment: this is the best because it's easy to remember

Answer (score 50):

```
lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}'
```

This will give you just the pid, tested on MacOS.

Comment: on MAC kill all pids on port 3000:
lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Comment: can more than one process listen to the same port?

Comment: Our rails app spawns workers which are child processes, and I have to use this to kill orphaned workers

Comment: this also kills webbrowsers connecting to port

Comment: Here is working one: `lsof -n -iTCP:3407 -sTCP:LISTEN -n -l -P | grep 'LISTEN' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

Answer (score 39):

Execute in command line on OS-X El Captain:

```
kill -kill `lsof -t -i tcp:3000`
```

Terse option of lsof returns just the PID.

Answer (score 33):

One of the ways to kill a process on a port is to use the python library: freeport (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/freeport/0.1.9) . Once installed, simply:

```
# install freeport
pip install freeport

# Once freeport is installed, use it as follows
$ freeport 3000
Port 3000 is free. Process 16130 killed successfully
```

Comment: That's, by far, NOT the simplest way.  The upvoted replies don't require you to download and install anything.

Comment: When the prerequisites are met this is so simple and easy to remember. We have a different definition of "simplest" and this answer is perfectly valid and appropriate. Maybe it's just missing the instructions to install freeport with pip.

Comment: under the hood, freeport is just a wrapper that calls `lsof -t -i:3000`.. seems unnecessary.

Comment: This solution is not the easiest, but it complies 100% with what the OP asked... So it is in deed valid AF

Answer (score 33):

To view the processes blocking the port:

`netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000`

To Kill the processes blocking the port:

`kill $(lsof -t -i :3000)`

Comment: This won't work on a Mac machine, returns the following:
`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`
It will, however, work in most linux distros

Comment: @MilanVelebit Actually it works perfectly in my Mac machine (Sierra). It works fine if your port `3000` is occupied. However if no processes is blocking the port, then you will get `kill: not enough arguments` error.

Comment: That's just weird, I've two Macs (both High Sierra tho), I remember running those commands on both of them (old habits) and I know for certain that they don't run. I've just tried it again on my machine, knowing that the port is occupied, same error. :/

Comment: Did you get a valid PID on running `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000`, for your port that's occupied?

Comment: I ran a `lsof -i :portname`, returned the process. Same goes for the `netstat` command, both output the process occupying the port correctly.

Comment: I tried it in both `bash` and `zsh` shell. Works fine for me. Not sure why it's not working for you. May be some thing to with High Sierra? I have no idea :/

Comment: @Henry The issue was that you should add sudo - otherwise `lsof -i` might return nothing

Answer (score 28):

Find and kill:

This single command line is easy and works correctly.

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti tcp:3000)
```

Answer (score 26):

**Find the open connection**

> lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"

**Kill by process ID**

> kill -9 'PID'

Answer (score 18):

Possible ways to achieve this:

**top**

The top command is the traditional way to view your system’s resource usage and see the processes that are taking up the most system resources. Top displays a list of processes, with the ones using the most CPU at the top.

**ps**

The ps command lists running processes. The following command lists all processes running on your system:

```
ps -A
```

You could also pipe the output through grep to search for a specific process without using any other commands. The following command would search for the Firefox process:

```
ps -A | grep firefox
```

The most common way of passing signals to a program is with the kill command.

```
kill PID_of_target_process
```

**lsof**

List of all open files and the processes that opened them.

```
lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
kill -9 PID
```

or

```
 lsof -i tcp:3000
```

Answer (score 13):

`lsof -i tcp:port_number` - will list the process running on that port

`kill -9 PID` - will kill the process

in your case, it will  be

`lsof -i tcp:3000` from your terminal
find the PID of process

`kill -9 PID`

Answer (score 12):

I made a little function for this, add it to your rc file (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or whatever)

```
function kill-by-port {
  if [ "$1" != "" ]
  then
    kill -9 $(lsof -ni tcp:"$1" | awk 'FNR==2{print $2}')
  else
    echo "Missing argument! Usage: kill-by-port $PORT"
  fi
}
```

then you can just type `kill-by-port 3000` to kill your rails server (substituting 3000 for whatever port it's running on)

failing that, you could always just type `kill -9 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)` from the rails root directory

Comment: I had to backslash `\$PORT` to get the message to display correctly. Otherwise, works great!

Answer (score 12):

These two commands will help you find and kill server process

> 1. lsof -wni tcp:3000
> 2. kill -9 pid

Comment: My pleasure, Aashiah

Answer (score 9):

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)
```

works for me on macOS always.

If you're working on a node.js project, you can add it to package.json scripts like;

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "killme": "kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)",
    ...
  },
```

then

```
npm run killme
```

--

Also if you want to add system wide alias for your macOS, follow these steps;

Navigate to your home directory:

```
cd ~
```

Open up .bash_profile or zsh profile using nano or vim:

```
vi .bash_profile
```

Add an alias (press i):

```
alias killme="kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)"
```

save file

restart terminal

type `killme` to the terminal

Of course you can change port 3000 to what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Add to `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
function killTcpListen () {
  kill -QUIT $(sudo lsof -sTCP:LISTEN -i tcp:$1 -t)
}
```

Then `source ~/.bash_profile` and run

`killTcpListen 8080`

Answer (score 6):

Using [sindresorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus)'s [fkill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fkill-cli) tool, you can do this:

```
$ fkill :3000
```

Answer (score 5):

Works for me for terminating **node** (Mac OS Catalina)

```
killall -9 node
```

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR:

```
lsof -ti tcp:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN | xargs kill
```

If you're in a situation where there are both clients and servers using the port, e.g.:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:3000
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node       2043 benjiegillam   21u  IPv4 0xb1b4330c68e5ad61      0t0  TCP localhost:3000->localhost:52557 (ESTABLISHED)
node       2043 benjiegillam   22u  IPv4 0xb1b4330c8d393021      0t0  TCP localhost:3000->localhost:52344 (ESTABLISHED)
node       2043 benjiegillam   25u  IPv4 0xb1b4330c8eaf16c1      0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)
Google    99004 benjiegillam  125u  IPv4 0xb1b4330c8bb05021      0t0  TCP localhost:52557->localhost:3000 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    99004 benjiegillam  216u  IPv4 0xb1b4330c8e5ea6c1      0t0  TCP localhost:52344->localhost:3000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

then you probably don't want to kill both.

In this situation you can use `-sTCP:LISTEN` to only show the pid of processes that are listening. Combining this with the `-t` terse format you can automatically kill the process:

```
lsof -ti tcp:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a helper bash function to kill multiple processes by name or port

```
fkill() {
  for i in $@;do export q=$i;if [[ $i == :* ]];then lsof -i$i|sed -n '1!p';
  else ps aux|grep -i $i|grep -v grep;fi|awk '{print $2}'|\
  xargs -I@ sh -c 'kill -9 @&&printf "X %s->%s\n" $q @';done
}
```

Usage:

```
$ fkill [process name] [process port]
```

Example:

```
$ fkill someapp :8080 node :3333 :9000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000
```

Answer (score 3):

I use:

`lsof -wni tcp:3000`

Get the PID, and:

`kill -9 <PID>`

Answer (score 3):

my fav one-liner:
`` sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:3000` ``

Answer (score 3):

To kill port 3000 on mac, run the below command

`kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN)`

Answer (score 3):

just write on terminal

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)
```

hope , it's work.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this, This technique is OS Independent.

In side your application there is a folder called tmp, inside that there is an another folder called pids. 
That file contains the server pid file.
Simply delete that file. port automatically kill itself.

I think this is the easy way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a code free way - open activity manager and force kill node :)

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

`cat tmp/pids/server.pid | pbcopy`

Then
`kill -9 'paste'`

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation of steps with terminal o/p

I have Macbook Pro (Catalina), 1 day I found the below issue while running the Django server (which runs on port 8000 by default):

> python manage.py runserver 3000

```
(venv) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:learn-django hygull$ python manage.py runserver 3000
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 27, 2021 - 23:54:05
Django version 3.2.3, using settings 'automated_classification.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.
```

---

I tried to use the provided and executed but running only 1 of them was not solving my problem (I know there were some other answers too but somehow I solved my problem). E.g. I tried to rerun the above command but that too did not work (still the processes were active).

So I finally I used answer of @Cris with 1 more additional step as he & others have suggested. So my answer is just using their commands with Terminal output to make the executions more clearer to you.

> lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}'

```
(venv) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:learn-django hygull$ lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}' 
36239
38272
```

---

Now I got the list of ids to kill, let's do.

> kill -9 <PID>

```
(venv) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:learn-django hygull$ kill -9 36239
(venv) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:learn-django hygull$ kill -9 36239
-bash: kill: (36239) - No such process
(venv) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:learn-django hygull$ kill -9 38272
(venv) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:learn-django hygull$ kill -9 38272
-bash: kill: (38272) - No such process
```

---

And now, let's try to rerun the command.

> python manage.py runserver 3000

```
(venv) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:learn-django hygull$ python manage.py runserver 3000
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 27, 2021 - 23:55:53
Django version 3.2.3, using settings 'project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

---

### FINAL

> kill -9 $(lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}')

You can combine the above 2 steps in 1 line & execute to kill process listening on port **3000**.

Answer (score 1):

After executing the kill commands, deleting the pid file might be necessary:

```
rm ~/mypath/myrailsapp/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Zsh, and don't want to remember multi-pipe commands, just add next lines of code to `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
function murder() {
    lsof -nti:$1 | xargs kill -9
}
```

And then any time you need to kill a process on a specific port, just use:

```sh
murder 3000
```

P.S feel free to rename the command and improve it :)

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: Find server which are running:
`ps aux | grep puma`
Step 2: Kill those server
Kill -9 [server number]

Answer (score -4):

In mac OS

`kill -9 $(lsof -i TCP:3000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: This was posted as a comment 5 years ago,  and simular answers were posted multiple times.

Answer (score -12):

You should try this code using the terminal:

```
$ killall -9 ruby
```