# Meteor (Meteorite) error: listen EADDRINUSE on port 3000, error: connect ECONNREFUSED on other ports

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am running meteorite (with a test project, so errors should not be due to anything I wrote) on OSX, and am getting the following error when I run on the default port 3000.  I have checked, and no other process is accessing that port.

event.js:72
    throw er;  \ Unhandled 'error' event
    Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoExeception: (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039.14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at net.js:1135:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

When I try to run mrt on a port I know is occupied, I get the correct error message (can't listen on port 3001), and when I try to run on another unoccupied port I get:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Any suggestions?

Further update:

I just did a complete shutdown/restart, picked a new port number (3200), checked that nothing is using that port or anything near it, and ran meteor --port 3200.  I got:

```
I20140115-14:02:29.623(-7)? ----------Wed Jan 15 2014 14:02:29 GMT-0700 (MST) SQL Driver Starting --------
W20140115-14:02:29.639(-7)? (STDERR) Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
W20140115-14:02:29.639(-7)? (STDERR)     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
W20140115-14:02:29.640(-7)? (STDERR)     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete]     (net.js:892:19)
W20140115-14:02:29.640(-7)? (STDERR)     --------------------
W20140115-14:02:29.641(-7)? (STDERR)     at Handshake.Sequence (/Users/a230073/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
W20140115-14:02:29.641(-7)? (STDERR)     at new Handshake (/Users/a230073/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:9:12)
W20140115-14:02:29.641(-7)? (STDERR)     at Protocol.handshake (/Users/a230073/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:41:50)
W20140115-14:02:29.642(-7)? (STDERR)     at PoolConnection.Connection.connect (/Users/a230073/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:73:18)
W20140115-14:02:29.642(-7)? (STDERR)     at Pool.getConnection (/Users/a230073/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:43:23)
W20140115-14:02:29.642(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/server/dbinit.js:13:6
W20140115-14:02:29.642(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/server/dbinit.js:79:3
W20140115-14:02:29.643(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/lfrey/Desktop/Thesis/test-meteor-sql/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140115-14:02:29.643(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140115-14:02:29.643(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/a230073/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be starting your app with `meteor` and not `mrt`. That convention changed a few releases ago.

If you had a previously running meteor process which did not exit properly, you'd get an `EADDRINUSE` error when you try to start another one on the same port. The easy solution is just to reboot. You could also try to find the process and manually kill it: run `ps aux | grep meteor`, and `kill PID` where `PID` is the process id (2nd column from the `ps` output). Of course it may be that you just have some other unrelated process using that port... but try the above first.

If you try to run your process on another port, e.g. `meteor --port 4000` that should work unless the port isn't available to you. For example, on *NIX machines, ports below 1024 require elevated privileges to use.

Comment: I have tried all of that: using 'meteor' instead, killing all meteor processes, restarting, and using another port.  When I try to run on another port (3002, 4000, etc) I instead get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: Did you kill all node processes also? I think meteor uses node in as a process not meteor itself

Comment: @Akshat Well he said he rebooted so unless he's hanging another process as soon as he starts, I wouldn't think that would be an issue.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac) question. I'm on linux so I can't test all these commands, but if your run something like `lsof -i tcp:3000` it should point you to the process which is using that port (should be `node` if it's a meteor process). I'd do that after a clean boot. I'm unsure why you'd get `ECONNREFUSED` on other ports, but that may be something else wacky with your environment.

Comment: Also you cant use port 3002, when you use meteor on port 3000, it would use ports 3001 and 3002 so if a meteor process is left running those ports would still be used.

Comment: I don't have anything running on port 3000, I've checked many times.  I do have another process listening on port 3001, which is why I started trying higher ports.  When I run meteor --port 4000, I can see using netstat that port 4000 is in use (by meteor), but meteor gives me the ECONNREFUSED error.

Comment: See update to my original question: restarting, etc. doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looking at your stack trace this error isn't about your meteor app's ports its something you're trying to connect to in your code. Your MySQL server is probably not enabled (it comes from server/dbinit.js) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with gulp...  You need to find the PSID of the port, then run 
kill -9 on the PSID number.  After you should be able to run it again.

```
sudo lsof -i :3200
sudo kill -9 PSID
```