# Why am I unable to kill my JBoss process?

Tags: jboss, osx-yosemite, restart, shutdown

I’m using JBoss wildfly 10.0.0.CR2 on Mac Yosemite.  I was looking for a foolproof way to kill JBoss so and was suggested this command

```
pgrep -d" " -f "wildfly" | xargs kill;
```

So I run this command and then I go into my $JBOSS_HOME/bin directory and run “sh standalone.sh” and get this disappointing output …

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro-2:bin davea$ sh standalone.sh 
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n

=========================================================================

ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
standalone.sh: line 302:  3096 Abort trap: 6           "java" -D"[Standalone]" -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2/standalone/log/server.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" -jar "/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2/jboss-modules.jar" -mp "/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2/modules" org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir="/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2" -Djboss.server.base.dir="/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2/standalone"
```

Does anyone know a foolproof way to kill JBoss once and for all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't remember who provided this answer but here is how to kill the WIldfly process

```
pgrep -d" " -f "wildfly" | xargs kill -9;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you don't provide a signal number it defaults to *TERM* signal.

You can use the following command to kill the process definitely:

> kill -9 [PID]

See this [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/kill.1.html)

And also this question:
[Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)