# could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

Tags: android, shell, sockets, tcp, adb

Hi I am new to `android` I am not able to run `adb.exe` it gives me below error:

```
==>adb start-server
adb I  6108  5748 adb.cpp:219] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
adb I  6108  5748 adb.cpp:219] Revision 09a0d98bebce-android
adb I  6108  5748 adb.cpp:219]
adb I  6108  5748 adb_client.cpp:126] _adb_connect: host:version
adb I  6108  5748 sysdeps_win32.cpp:742] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
adb I  6108  5748 adb_client.cpp:175] adb_connect: service host:start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

What does this error exactly mean..?

```
Cannot open 'nul': The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
```

What is this error..?

Comment: Firewall might be a problem

Comment: I disabled firewall as well as Quick heal antivirus and tried again I get same error

Comment: Do the `telnet` from your windows and check are you able to connect or not.

Comment: you mean to say `telnet 127.0.0.1 5037`..? It gives `Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5037: Connect failed`

Comment: Please refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706913/4374362) answer which helped me!

Answer (score 26):

make sure you have installing your device driver and `adb` service
and is activated USB debugging in `android device -> setting -> developer options`
 and must be could to see your device when you connected by USB port ( by this command : `adb devices`)
so when you connected by USB follow this Commands :
1-stay connect via USB

2-connect to your WIFI network (computer and mobile device both)

3-`ping DeviceIP` (must be have ping to your device)

4- `adb kill-server`

5-`adb usb`

6-`adb tcpip 5556`

7-`adb connect "yourDeviceIP:5556"`

8-`adb devices` (must be see two device names , one of them is by deviceIP:5556)

9-unplug USB cable

 then it's Done! and you could to test your app

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer which helped me. The issue might be with the latest unstable version of platform-tools.

[adb cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131020/adb-cannot-connect-to-daemon-at-tcp5037)

Answer (score 0):

In my computer, it is releated to Hyper-V, I have to completely disabled it. Then the ports like 5037,5055,8080 and so on are avaliable.

See more on https://petri.com/how-to-disable-hyper-v-completely-in-windows-10, https://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/.

DO NOT FORGET `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and it was because of the antivirus that was not not allowing to connect with my device. So, I deleted the adb.exe from platform-tools and pasted it again.
[Please store the adb.exe before deleting]

After doing this, I got a pop-up from my antivirus software asking if it can allow devices to connect. On clicking OK, I got the authentication key from the device. On checking it, I was able to connect successfully.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your real device is on `developer mode`. I am using `Poco M2 Pro` and I had enabled it before around `15 day`. But today it suddenly turned off developer mode.

Answer (score -1):

it seems your adb is listening in *tcpip mode* for connecting over wifi..kill the server using `adb kill-server`..start it again using `adb usb`

Else also try l-> Go to task manager and kill adb process. ..

Comment: I tried this adb kill-server but it gives me same error `adb I  3440  5400 sysdeps_win32.cpp:742] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
* server not running *`

Comment: yes ti tried `adb usb` as well gives same error. Even I reinstalled Android SDK still gives me same error...

Comment: Turn off usb debugging on phone and try

Comment: Ohh strange I have not connected my phone to pc and `adb.exe` is not showing in task manager...

Comment: what should I do ? Do need to format whole system now ? or any other solution.?

Comment: @JDev try using another device..Even I faced the same scenario but after performed the steps which I told it started working fine..r u trying to connect the phone via wifi

Answer (score -3):

`adb.exe` might be corrupted , try to replace these files

```
ADB.exe
AdbWinApi.dll
AdbWinUsbApi.dll
```

from the latest [SDK Platform-Tools for Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip)