# Unable to connect to android devices via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I want to control my android phones and tablet using `adb` command, but I only could connect to one of them and the two others failed:

Here is what I have tasted from the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327974/could-not-connect-to-tcp5037-cannot-connect-to-127-0-0-15037-no-connection-c/41321064) solution to this topic:

```
D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>ping 10.42.0.16

Pinging 10.42.0.16 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.42.0.16: bytes=32 time=326ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.42.0.16: bytes=32 time=291ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.42.0.16: bytes=32 time=158ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.42.0.16: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.42.0.16:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 18ms, Maximum = 326ms, Average = 198ms

D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server
* server not running *

D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb usb
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: no devices/emulators found

D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 10.42.0.16:5555
unable to connect to 10.42.0.16:5555: cannot connect to 10.42.0.16:5555 : No conn
ection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

The successful connection android device information:

Galaxy S7, Android 6.0.1

Two Failed devices information:

Huawei G525-U00, Android 4.1.2

Galaxy Note 10, Android 4.4.2

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have SDK 16 installed?

Comment: Where can I check that?

Comment: SmAster- Go to android installation folder & check it

Comment: In platforms folder, I have android-2 to android-25 and in build-tools I have 17.0.0 to 25.0.2.

Comment: Why downvote the question?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#4.1

Comment: You have build tools, but maybe you need full API 16 sdk to make it work. since it is working on 6.0.1 android. you should download full files for the 4.1.2 Android too

Comment: @SmAster, Thanks, could you provide me a download link where can I find build tools for API 16?

Comment: Yes check COmments here

Comment: @SmAster,  I couldn't find the downloadable link of build tools for API 16. The link contains the description of it or maybe i miss it.

Comment: https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-41-api-16-jelly-bean-direct.html

Comment: @SmAster, Thanks I couldn't find build tools for API 16, There are 19.1 above.  https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-build-tools.html

Comment: Bcz this api in 10 Generates below lol