# Must restart computer to run expo bundler in tunnel mode every time I want to restart it?

Tags: react-native, debugging, tcp, expo, tunnel

Running expo bundler for react native in tunnel mode with `expo start --tunnel` only works the first time I run it after a fresh restart of my computer. Then, if for some reason I close the cmd prompt that is tracking expo and open another, running the same command gives this error:

`Error starting tunnel could not connect to TCP port 5562: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5562: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)`

I think there has to be an easy way to resolve this since restarting works. Does anyone know where to start?

I've checked the following threads to no avail:

[could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327974/could-not-connect-to-tcp5037-cannot-connect-to-127-0-0-15037-no-connection-c)

https://pisquare.osisoft.com/thread/42096-could-not-connect-to-nettcpwin-fvo35t9cv2q5457afserverservice-the-connection-attempt-lasted-for-a-time-span-of-0000020312902-tcp-error-code-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-1921681691285457