# Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: express, gulp, polymer, nodemon

I use the following example to setup an express server: https://github.com/sogko/gulp-recipes/tree/master/browser-sync-nodemon-expressjs .

I use gulp to kickstart several processes like minifying, vulcanizing and folding up my Polymer project.

The gulpfile.js is 364 lines big, but this is the part that matters:

```
// Build and serve the output from the dist build
appsPaths.forEach(function(app) {
  gulp.task('serve:dist:' + app,
    ['browser-sync', 'default:' + app]);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function () {

  // for more browser-sync config options: http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    snippetOptions: {
      rule: {
        match: '<span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>',
        fn: function (snippet) {
          return snippet;
        }
      }
    },

    // informs browser-sync to proxy our expressjs app which would run at the following location
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000',

    // informs browser-sync to use the following port for the proxied app
    // notice that the default port is 3000, which would clash with our expressjs
    port: 4000,

    // open the proxied app in chrome
    browser: ['google-chrome']
  });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
  var called = false;
  return $.nodemon({

    // nodemon our expressjs server
    script: 'server/app.js',

    // watch core server file(s) that require server restart on change
    watch: ['server/app.js']
  })
    .on('start', function onStart() {
      // ensure start only got called once
      if (!called) { cb(); }
      called = true;
    })
    .on('restart', function onRestart() {
      // reload connected browsers after a slight delay
      setTimeout(function reload() {
        browserSync.reload({
          stream: false
        });
      }, BROWSER_SYNC_RELOAD_DELAY);
    });
});
```

Now while this works great and all I still get the following error ending up in my gulp log:

```
^CDaniels-iMac:polymer dani$ gulp serve:dist:domain.com
[22:33:10] Using gulpfile ~/dev/company/polymer/gulpfile.js
[22:33:10] Starting 'nodemon'...
[22:33:10] Starting 'clean:domain.com'...
[22:33:10] Finished 'clean:domain.com' after 8.56 ms
[22:33:10] Starting 'default:domain.com'...
[22:33:10] Starting 'copy:domain.com'...
[22:33:10] Starting 'styles:domain.com'...
[22:33:11] Finished 'styles:domain.com' after 295 ms
[22:33:11] [nodemon] 1.9.2
[22:33:11] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[22:33:11] [nodemon] watching: server/app.js
[22:33:11] [nodemon] starting `node server/app.js`
[22:33:11] Finished 'nodemon' after 570 ms
[22:33:11] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[22:33:11] Finished 'browser-sync' after 20 ms
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at net.js:1379:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:63:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:82:10)
[22:33:11] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[BS] Proxying: http://localhost:3000
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:4000
    External: http://10.0.1.28:4000
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.0.1.28:3001
 ----------------------------------
[22:33:12] copy all files 16.03 MB
[22:33:12] Finished 'copy:domain.com' after 1.78 s
[22:33:12] Starting 'elements:domain.com'...
[22:33:12] Finished 'elements:domain.com' after 5.39 ms
[22:33:12] Starting 'jshint:domain.com'...
[22:33:12] Starting 'images:domain.com'...
[22:33:12] Starting 'fonts:domain.com'...
[22:33:12] Starting 'html:domain.com'...
[22:33:12] Finished 'images:domain.com' after 339 ms
[22:33:12] Finished 'fonts:domain.com' after 157 ms
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
```

This is what I see before and after triggering a run of the gulp script:

```
Daniels-iMac:polymer dani$ lsof -i tcp:3000
Daniels-iMac:polymer dani$
Daniels-iMac:polymer dani$ lsof -i tcp:3000
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    95580 dani   19u  IPv4 0x8560662b0408bad3      0t0  TCP localhost:hbci (LISTEN)
```

So it appears there's not a lot going on on port 3000. What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like you already have node running on port 3000. you can kill the process check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac

Comment: I've got that covered. It's either not running on port 3000 or I got one pid result when I run `lsof -i tcp:3000` depending on whether I got gulp running or not. So it's not that there's already another process running, I've tried several other impossible ports: all produce the same error. it appears it's more like the express server somehow starts up twice using nodemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running browserSync with the same ports several times on `http://localhost:3000` due to the forEach, which I assume has several paths.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a negative. When firing a console.log in both the nodemon and the browser-sync task function, both of them only trigger once. The same counts for adding only one item to the appsPath array: the problem persists. This behaviour is as expected, because when running a gulp.task function, you only define the task itself. You do not run it.

Comment: d0h! While it wasn't exactly that. I forgot a tryout require statement that runned the server on the top of my gulpfile and thus was overlooked. Thanks for your help Wilson Alberto

Comment: I'm glad you found the root cause! Gulp could use some better debugging tools, this feels like one of those issues that would be solved by logging the tasks