# shopify store won't run the code in script tag, error generated

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have installed a script tag in my shopify store. It is supposed to run when I load my store, when I look in my network panel, I can see that it was loaded but it failed. when I look under the console, it generated an error
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. why is my store refusing to run my code?

post data looks like this

```js
var postdata = {
    "script_tag":{
        "event":"onload",
        "display_scope":"online_store",
        "src":"https://localhost:3000/testscript.js"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of reasons why your script tag could not be working. A few solutions are listed below:

1) Your URI should begin with "http://" (without the "s") seeing as this is a localhost server.

2) Try unchecking proxy server for your lan 127.0.0.1 through internet properties (how to locate this depends on your platform).

3) Port 3000 could already be in use, so try using something else like the widely-known 8080 or 1337. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac) for more information on killing a Port 300 in use.