# Node.js Unable to start server

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm confused a) what the actual error is here - it seems some people with this missing module can still start their server, b) How can I fix this?

I've tried:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

npm-debug.log provided no additional errors/obviously useful info. This is a beginner setup using Express that makes a small query to MongoDB.

npm start output:

```
david@david-desktop:~/Documents/node/nodetest1$ npm start

> nodetest1@0.0.0 start /home/david/Documents/node/nodetest1
> node ./bin/www

{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Port 3000 is already in use

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! nodetest1@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the nodetest1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs nodetest1
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodetest1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/david/Documents/node/nodetest1/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Port 3000 is already in use
```

Please try killing the old process running on port 3000 or try using another port.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article for killing the process which is running on port number 3000,

[Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)

Otherwise, Change the port number