# Shiny Server Error on webpage: An error has occurred The application failed to start. The application exited during initialization

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to setup R Shiny Server on my Amazon Linux AWS EC2 instance and am getting the following error:

An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

The application exited during initialization.

I did a sudo shiny-server to see what happens and see the error EADDRINUSE:

```
$ sudo shiny-server
[2017-01-29 13:21:22.724] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server        v1.5.1.834 (Node.js v6.9.1)
[2017-01-29 13:21:22.728] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file   "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2017-01-29 13:21:22.764] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on   0.0.0.0:80
[2017-01-29 13:21:22.771] [ERROR] shiny-server - HTTP server error (0.0.0.0:80): listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:80
[2017-01-29 13:21:22.771] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

I have verified that Shiny, rmarkdown and, Shiny Server and R are properly installed on my instance:

```
R --version
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

> library(shiny)
> library(rmarkdown)
>
```

I have also checked the network connection on my ec2 instance:

```
$ sudo netstat --tcp -nlpa | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                    LISTEN      1875/shiny-server
```

My ec2 instance network security group:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-name launch-wizard-7
{
"SecurityGroups": [
    {
        "IpPermissionsEgress": [
            {
                "IpProtocol": "-1", 
                "PrefixListIds": [], 
                "IpRanges": [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ], 
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                "Ipv6Ranges": []
            }
        ], 
        "Description": "launch-wizard-7 created 2017-01-28T14:22:51.817-05:00", 
        "IpPermissions": [
            {
                "PrefixListIds": [], 
                "FromPort": 80, 
                "IpRanges": [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ], 
                "ToPort": 80, 
                "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                "Ipv6Ranges": []
            },
```

(there's another entry but that ssh into my own machine so I won't put that information)

and here is my shiny-server.conf file from /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

```
$ cat /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
    listen 3838;

# Define a location at the base URL
location / {

# Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

# Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

# When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
# an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
 }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I tried to let AWS listen to request for port 80 for all ip addresses and for the shiny-server as I thought maybe both services shouldn't be listening to the same port but that didn't work. Am just trying to deploy the sample-app that came with shiny server.

url: http://34.198.107.126/sample-apps/hello/

Comment: I am also wandering if my AWS security group should allow inbound traffic for port 80 for all ip's and shiny-server listen to port 3838 or the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

nevermind, figured out what it was; everything was setup properly but my r packages were not installed as root but as ec2-user; installing as root worked as the webpages/folders permissions are mostly root.

Comment: are you sure reloading all packages as root was the problem? In my case I can run from inside rstudio from the `Run App` button at the top right but if you go to a browser and try to access the shiny app using the `<public IP address>/shiny/rstudio` it gives the same error as you get,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error because **the port was already in use** (a crashed process could be hogging the port, or a legitimate program could be using it).

A simple solution could be to try on another port. Otherwise try some/all of the following:

To [check to see if any process is using the port](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/153#issuecomment-150313933) you're trying to use (change 3838 to the port you're interested in):

```sh
netstat  -an | grep 3838 

tcp46      0      0  *.3838                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

If you see something there, you know the port is in use (a port that isn't in use won't return any result).

To [see what process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855359/5783745) is using port 3838:

```sh
lsof -i tcp:3838   

COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 23298   st  115u  IPv6 0xfa130c123d3bd073      0t0  TCP *:sos (LISTEN)
```

If you're happy to [kill the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706913/5783745) (use the process ID found above):

```sh
kill -9 23298
```

After this the shiny app worked as expected.