# Shiny-app error: The application failed to start. The application exited during initialization

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny server on which I have deployed two apps.  They run fine. I tried to deploy a third app using exactly the same protocol and when I try to invoke from its url I get this error:

The application failed to start.

The application exited during initialization.

I examined the file permissions for the app.R file for all three apps and they are identical.  I also see nothing in the log file (var/log/shiny-server) hat points to an obvious problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not post the contents of your logfile? It definitely contains the error that prevented running the app. Most likely a package is not installed, or a library call is missing.

Comment: Just a trick I use often (not for purists!).  Load rstudio on the shiny server and run the app from there.  This doesn't use the actual shiny server, but it allows quickly to debug obvious things: are all the packages loaded working ok etc. (I also use `chmod -R 777 <shiny serv. folder(s)` initially), I can test the database conn. on the shiny server etc.  If the app works within rstudio, then you may have a file permission issue on shiny server (or something `directly` linked to the server) or the server cannot access the packages. Clean up & put everything back when all works. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I missed a source call.  The error message wasn't particularly informative but it was, ultimately, a simple fix.

Comment: I had the same error because the port I was using was busy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71858722/5783745) for diagnosis and how to resolve.