# NodeJS - npm start every time gets error Port is already in use

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing an application with NodeJS and Express and every time I have to `npm start` I get the error Port is already in use. I have to change the port in www file and `npm start` again.

I am using Mac BTW.
How to solve this issuse?

Is there any good module for live reload?

Comment: Can you add your server init script?

Comment: Why not simply just change the port wherever you're declaring it?

Comment: What port are you having issues with? Do you have a multiple instances running simultaneously?

Comment: Im getting same issue. First time it runs on 8080 port and second time when I refresh, output is not changing & it says port already in use. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, looks like you are not stopping the server before starting again.

A simple and painless way would be to use nodemon (https://nodemon.io). It acts on changes of your code and restarts the server. You will have to reload the browser yourself.

```
npm i -g nodemon
nodemon [app|server|yourservername].js
```

Live Reload goes a step further, as it triggers the browser to reload the page (using websockets). You may check out supervisor as suggested. I personally prefer lite-server, which requires no configuration to get live reload. Just start it in your applications root directory.

```
npm i -g lite-server
lite-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a dev script so you don't have to use npm start. This example uses supervisor https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor

Create a file called `dev.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

ENV=dev \
  node_modules/supervisor/lib/cli-wrapper.js \
  --watch ., ../core \ # replace this with your paths to watch
  --ignore-symlinks \
  --ignore node_modules,public,client,data \
  --extensions js \
  --quiet \
  --non-interactive \
  --no-restart-on error \
  --instant-kill \
app.js # your server script here
```

Then when you want to dev just run `sh dev`. This question deals with killing processes on nix: [Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)