# Equivalent of netstat -pant with the Mac

Tags: macos, netstat

In Ubuntu, to see the listening process I used to do the following command netstat -pant I would get something similar to this

[image: Credits to samclass.info]

What is the equivalent command with the Mac ?

Answer (score 10):

*(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855359/2708650))*

To show the processes, you would use `netstat -vanp tcp`. This doesn't translate the PIDs to process names, but you could do an `awk` using `ps` to translate them. Alternatively, you could go straight to `sudo lsof -i tcp` and get a slightly different layout that maps ports to named processes.

Here's an example (newlines added for readability):

```
netstat -vanp tcp |
  awk 'BEGIN { l=0 }
       { if (l == 0) { print $0 }
         else if (l == 1) { print $0, "process" }
         else { "ps -o comm " $9 "| tail -1" | getline line;
                print $0, line }
         l++; }'
```

If you want UDP results instead, just specify `udp` instead of `tcp`.

Comment: Thank for the answer, pratically how would you use awk?

Comment: That's amazing, seriously good!