# Firebase serve error: Port 5000 is not open. Could not start functions emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

I'm trying to serve firebase functions locally, but when I run `firebase serve` or `firebase emulators:start` the error message is: "Port 5000 is not open, could not start functions emulator."

I'm using Windows 10, so I've tried to change the port number, check if the port is blocked by Firewall and I create a new rule in Firewall to ports 5000-5010 but none of this approaches worked for me.

Comment: Have the same problem, on MacOS. Reverted to firebase-tools version 6.12.0 for now and that seems to work (although not a real solution to the problem). `npm i -g firebase-tools@6.12.0`

Comment: using firebase-tools@6.12.0 generated grpc related error in node module, the latest firebase-tools doesn't have this error. => reverting back to v6.12.0 did not work for me :(

Comment: @Thr3e This happened to me, too. So, I installed the grpc module in functions folder and it worked again

Comment: In my case, I had `AirServer` running, which was using the `5001` port. So I closed it once I saw `publicmat`'s answer.

Answer (score 64):

For Mac/Linux, use the Terminal/Shell to find the Process ID (PID), then kill the process.

```
sudo lsof -i :5000
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Comment: `lsof -t -i tcp:5000 | xargs kill` - one line alternative that pipes the output of lsof to kill (h/t [@manav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac/3855359#3855359))

Comment: If you are using macOS Monterey, the Airplay server now uses Port 5000 so you either need to change the port for your process or kill Airplay receiver in System Preferences > Sharing

Comment: @warfield lsof -t -i tcp:5000 | xargs kill didn't help :(

Answer (score 61):

In **MacOS Monterey**, port 5000 may be claimed by a new "AirPlay Receiver". This can be disabled in Settings -> Sharing:

[Screenshot of settings panel for disabling AirPlay Receiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlt4g.png)

Disabling the AirPlay Receiver (if you do not need it) frees up port 5000.

Answer (score 43):

Alternatively use a different port, it is a simple solution.

```
firebase serve -p 5001
```

Answer (score 21):

For Windows Users:

```
netstat -ano|findstr "PID :5000"
```

And then with the Process ID (PID) found at the end of the line.

```
taskkill /pid FOUNDPID /F
```

Command `taskkill` does not work from within terminal of VS Code context. It needs an (elevated) CMD-prompt or equivalent Powershell environment in order to successfully terminate the listening on 127.0.0.1:5000.

Answer (score 15):

```
lsof -t -i tcp:5000 | xargs kill
```

A one-line alternative for Mac users that pipes the the process ID directly to `kill`.   h/t [@manav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855359/13995622)

Original question was for Windows, but might be useful for others as question is now ranked highly in search results.

Answer (score 15):

Port `5000` and `7000` are taken by airplay on MacOS Monterey.

Switch off Airplay Receiver as suggested [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332) or

update `firebase.json` with a different port

```
"emulators": {
   
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5004
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The thing here is your port No 5000 is running with some process.
So, first, you need to kill that process.

**Find process id in Ubuntu**

```
sudo lsof -i :5000
```

Suppose you get PID 14541

**Kill the process**

```
sudo kill -9 14541
```

Answer (score 4):

A similiar problem has recently been reported in the official github repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1606.

It is caused by a bug in a dependency (node portfinder), as you can see here. https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/pull/86

A quick fix to edit it might be to use the old version of node portfinder (v 1.0.21). Alternatively, you can do it by editing `node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/controller.js` and changing `yield pf.getPortPromise({ port, stopPort: port })` to `yield pf.getPortPromise({ port, stopPort: port + 1 })`.

EDIT:
As suggested by Mladen Skrbic, in order to find the `firebase-tools` folder, you should run `npm root -g` and find the `firebase-tools` folder in there.

This should fix the issue!

Comment: thank you it fixed my issue, i just want to say that npm root -g will tell you where to look

Comment: One line fix on OSX:

`sed -i '' 's/stopPort: port/stopPort: port+1/' node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/controller.js`

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

Just restart your system.

Comment: Actually just restarting the code editor also worked fine, thanks though!

Answer (score 4):

just run command

```
firebase serve --only functions --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Running this command did the trick for me:

```
firebase emulators:start --only firestore
```

also close this window:
[image: cmd window to close]

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
firebase serve --only functions -p 5002
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of latest firebase-functions(which is 3.2.0 currently), forcing it to stay at 3.0.2 solved in my case.

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
        "firebase-functions": "3.0.2",
        ...
    }
```

(Also I am using firebase-tools version 7.0.2 atm, didnt check it with latest. If it doesnt work try reverting firebase-tools to 7.0.2)

Comment: Facing the problem in version 7.2.2 of firebase-tools, but working in version 7.0.2 as suggested (thanks) as well as latest version 7.2.4.

Comment: In any firebase-tools version, only works with firebase-functions 3.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix

```
npm i -g firebase-tools@7.8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

macOS Monterey 12.2 user here. I've simply changed the port to 5005 and it worked like a charm.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "functions/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrapp"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": "5005"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION TO:**

> Firebase serve error: Port 5000 is not open. Could not start functions emulator

If you get one of the following error messages when you run Firebase, you can easily resolve the problem by switching to another version of Firebase tools.

If you are using version 6 of Firebase Tools, you might switch to latest version (6.12.0), or you might try v7.2.2. To change to Firebase Tools version run to following node package manager command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@6.12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5005
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.6 ,
I just changed the hosting port to "5005" , and it's working fine to me

Answer (score 0):

If `firebase serve --host 127.0.0.1` solves it for you; maybe you haven't set up your `hosts` file. [Linux - Network configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Network_configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue not quite long ago.

I found out I had firebase running on another terminal on my computer.

So before you try `firebase serve`, check if it is running on another terminal.

I hope it solves your problem just like mine.

Answer (score 0):

first, close all tab restart VS code then just go in firebase.json file then
change ui port number then start again, it will work!

```json
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": "enter any number"
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2856#issuecomment-902411134

Upgrading Node.js is working.

> I just upgraded Node to 14.17.5. This solves the problem. I just press Ctrl+C to stop all emulators.

Answer (score 0):

close everything, delete your "prefetch" and "%temp%" in "run" option and restart your PC. that worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

firebase serve --only functions --port

Answer (score -1):

For me, it wasn't working when a VPN was on.