# Error: Port 5000 is not open, could not start functions emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/socialape-6b2f7/overview
Ayhan-MacBookPro:socialape-functions macbook$ firebase serve

=== Serving from '/Users/macbook/Desktop/socialape-functions'...

Error: Port 5000 is not open, could not start functions emulator.

Answer (score 5):

Run `lsof -t -i tcp:5000 | xargs kill` from your Terminal.

A common cause for this error occurs when the Firebase emulator is not cleanly shut down (e.g., closing your IDE that's running the emulator in an embedded Terminal session)   This will leave the process running in the background and occupies the emulator's default port.

To resolve the conflict, find the process ID running on the port (here 5000) from your Terminal command line and then kill it.

The above one-liner finds the process ID and pipes it directly to `kill` (h/t [@manav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855359/13995622)).

For additional info, check out: [Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac/3855359#3855359)

Comment: this nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be on not your end

It is caused by a bug in a dependency (node portfinder).

A quick fix to edit it might be to use the old version of node portfinder (v 1.0.21). Alternatively, you can do it by editing node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/controller.js and changing yield pf.getPortPromise({ port, stopPort: port }) to yield pf.getPortPromise({ port, stopPort: port + 1 }).

You can see the answer to your question completely here in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537355/firebase-serve-error-port-5000-is-not-open-could-not-start-functions-emulator) SO link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in macOS Pro then this solution is for you.

In MacOS , Port 5000 may be claimed by a new "AirPlay Receiver".
This can be disabled in Settings -> Sharing:

I'm also adding the Screenshot of settings panel for disabling AirPlay Receiver.

Disabling the AirPlay Receiver (if you do not need it) frees up port 5000.

[image]