# Firebase functions: shell Error: Port 9001 is not open on localhost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I was unable to run functions shell without the emulators. It always error'd with

```
Error: Port 9001 is not open on localhost, could not start functions emulator.
```

I'm running a Mac with

```
  "firebase": "^7.24.0",
  "firebase-admin": "^9.9.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
```

and here's my firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": "9001"
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": "9002",
      "rules": "firestore.rules"
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": "9004"
    }
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public":"public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/**", 
      "dynamicLinks": true
    } ]
  }
}
```

When running emulators and functions together I get a warning saying you might get unusual behaviour so it doesn't look like its the correct solution.

I tried this but it didn't work in my case but worth noting:
[Firebase serve error: Port 5000 is not open. Could not start functions emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537355/firebase-serve-error-port-5000-is-not-open-could-not-start-functions-emulator)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, instead of in the question. That way you can accept it (which makes it more findable), and others can upvote it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Posting hoping to help someone out. In your `firebase.json` make sure your port number is a `number` not a `string`.

So

```
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 9001
    },
```

Not

```
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": "9001"
    }
```