# Is there a Git Bash command to deactivate all my active localhosts at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, git-bash, npm-start

When creating a react app, I run these commands in my terminal:

1. `npx create-react-app app-name`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start`

npm start allows me to view my project locally, but I accidently closed my terminal before running `ctrl + c` to end it. The browswer tab containing localhost 3000 (the `npm start` default host) has been closed for a while now, but my project can still be viewed there everytime I follow that link. Now everytime I run `npm start` it tells me that localhost 3000 is taken and I have to input another command and run it on localhost 3001. I've made this mistake a few times. I don't mind doing this, but it got me wondering if there is a global version of `ctrl + c` that will close all of these at once.

Comment: have you tried `ps aux` followed by `kill 12345` where 12345 is an example of a PID (process ID) that you read from an output line of the ps command and that looks like what you want to stop?

Comment: Firstly, make it clear which OS you are on. Secondly, you should search within your running/started processes and kill the already started process. Beside @WalterTross suggestion, you can use netstat and see which process is using port 3000.

Comment: I forgot: `kill -9 12345` is more guaranteed to work (it sends the `SIGKILL` signal instead of the default `SIGTERM` one)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you've had a misconceptions here: closing the browser tab will never end the server that you've started (i.e. the server `npm start` created).

For your question I think you can use the approach of killing a process based on the port they're occupying in this question:
[Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)