# Finding the PID listening to a port

Tags: bash, macos, react-fullstack

I use a bash script to run both the frontend and the backend of my full-stack application on `macOS`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PORT="3001"
export API_PORT="5001"
export MAIN_URL="http://localhost:"

cd Client
npm run dev &
cd ..
nodemon index.js &
```

The issue is that I want to kill the `PID` listening to the port before I execute the npm and nodemon commands. Is there a way I can get the specific PID?
Can I write the listening PID to a `.pid` file and then read from it when I want to kill?

Comment: You coul use `netstat -tanlp`  or search from `/proc/net/dev`....

Comment: Another way is using `fuser -k -n tcp $PORT`

Comment: @LéaGris gives me "Unknown option: k
Unknown option: n"

Comment: At this moment, this question has 0 upvotes, 0 downvotes, 2 answers, 2 comments trying to answer, and 2 close votes for _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
pid=$(sudo lsof -i :3001 -t)
kill $pid
```

Comment: this works! thanks (no need for the sudo)

Comment: You want to avoid the [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); you can refactor to just `sudo lsof -i :3001 -F | sed -n 's/^p//p'` ... but of course with `lsof -t` you don't need the pipe at all.