# Sanity Start compiles however localhost:3333 returns nothing

Tags: api, localhost, port, sanity

Good day all... I have been having an issue with Sanity for the past 3 days... After running sanity start on my linux vps I get the success message `Content Studio successfully compiled! Go to http://localhost:3333` however the link returns nothing - it just loads indefinitely without any error message in my console. I have tried chrome, brave and firefox as well as turning third-party cookies on - I'd appreciate any assistance or ideas as to what the problem may be

Comment: From Sanity v3, it should be `sanity dev` to run the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

If simply re-starting Sanity Studio doesn't work, you might check if there's still a thread running after exiting studio, and if so, terminate the thread and start Studio again.

A simple CLI command that kills the process running on port 3333 is:

`lsof -t -i tcp:3333 | xargs kill`

I've experienced similar issues with Studio being unresponsive after inadvertently leaving it running when my MBP goes to sleep. When I return, it appears Sanity is still running in the terminal, but there is no browser response and no errors thrown in the terminal.

More resources that might help:

- [Finding the PID of the process using a specific port?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port)
- [Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)